# AEM 6.5 Parallel Multiple approvals workflow

Tags: workflow, aem, multi-user

I have a requirement where i need to get approvals from multiple users and workflow can be proceeded to the next step when all the users  have approved. I wanted to know how we can achieve or design a single workflow model to achieve the requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can add a separate participant step for each approver/approverGroup. Afte r approval from one approver/approverGroup, next step would send approval request to next one.
Once all are done, you can proceed further.

OR
Complex one [Not recommended]
You can create your custom process step to send notifcation to all approvers and in the next operation, proceed only when each one of them has approved[keep that record on seprate node of each workflow instance ]

Comment: Why the custom process method is Not Recommended?

Comment: It would require a lot more custom code. But again it totally depends on your requirement what to follow.